# Beginner en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, programación-móvil, casting

Soy nueva trabajando con Android Studio. Estoy realizando una actividad de calculadura, y agradeceria su ayuda y explicación en lo siguiente.

Teniendo el código en la parte inferior, por qué es requerido castear las variables de tipo **Button** y cuando configuró el ***setOnClickListener*** va un this dentro de los ()

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{


    private EditText num1, num2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        

        num1 = findViewById(R.id.campo1);
        num2 = findViewById(R.id.campo2);

        Button btn_Suma = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSuma);
        btn_Suma.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button btn_Resta = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnResta);
        btn_Resta.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        Button btn_Multip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMultiplicacion);
        btn_Multip.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button btn_Division = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDivision);
        btn_Division.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView respuesta =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewResultado);
        respuesta.setText( suma( Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString()),Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString()) )+"");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **por qué es requerido castear las variables de tipo Button**

Actualmente no es requerido castear las variables a tipo Button ya que es una vista, por lo tanto puedes realizar esto únicamente:

```
    ...
    ...
    Button btn_Suma = findViewById(R.id.btnSuma);
    btn_Suma.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button btn_Resta = findViewById(R.id.btnResta);
    btn_Resta.setOnClickListener(this);
    
    Button btn_Multip = findViewById(R.id.btnMultiplicacion);
    btn_Multip.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button btn_Division = findViewById(R.id.btnDivision);
    btn_Division.setOnClickListener(this);
    ...
    ...
```

> **y cuando configuró el setOnClickListener va un this dentro de los ()**

Se usa `this` porque estas haciendo referencia a la clase `MainActivity`  que implementa  `View.OnClickListener`.

de otra forma si no deseas implementar en tu clase   `View.OnClickListener` entonces tendrías que definir el listener por cada botón:

```
    Button btn_Suma = findViewById(R.id.btnSuma);
    btn_Suma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //Realiza suma...       
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

En realidad, no es necesario castear los views (Button, Textview...) en Android Studio. Al menos no en las últimas versiones. Prueba sin castearlos y verás que te funciona igualmente, siempre y cuando tengas alguna de las últimas versiones del lenguaje.

Manera antigua:

```
Button btn_Division = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDivision);
```

Actualmente:

```
Button btn_Division = findViewById(R.id.btnDivision);
```

Por otra parte, si estás implementando la interface OnClickListener (implements View.OnClickListener), el *this* es una manera de hacer referencia a esa interface.

Luego en el método onClick(View v) tendrás que hacer distinción sobre cuál View es el que llama a la interface. Algo así:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
          case R.id.btn_Suma :
              // Tú código de suma
              break;
          case R.id.btn_Resta :
              // Tú código de resta
              break;
          default:
              // Método por defecto
              break;
        }

    }
```

Y así con el resto.